# Create roll-on script using Database Project that does not require SqlCmd

Tags: database-project

When using database projects, compare, and then Generate Script then the generated scripts is default for SqlCmd. E.g. it generates a row like:

```
/*
Detect SQLCMD mode and disable script execution if SQLCMD mode is not supported.
To re-enable the script after enabling SQLCMD mode, execute the following:
SET NOEXEC OFF; 
*/
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
```

Is it possible to generate scripts in the Database Project that just generates the stuff that can be executed via SQL Server Management Studio?

(I use Visual Studio 2022)

Answer (score 1):

I did not quite understand your question, but you helped me solve a problem. I was getting SQL80001 errors when editing my `*.sql` files. To suppress the errors, I needed to set the following Visual Studio 2022 (v17.5.5) Options:

[image: Options/SQL Server Tools/Transact-SQL Editor/Query Execution/General: Default SQLCMD mode]

[image: Options/SQL Server Tools/Transact-SQL Editor/Query Execution/Advanced: SET NOEXEC]